# Options to do a "mini-dsl" with Python?

Tags: python, testing, dsl

I am currently working on a framework to automate the configuration of our software product within virtual machines for testing purposes in python. So far, things are pretty object oriented. The framework will create "target" objects, and then depended on the type of target, the framework adds "actions" to a list; finally these actions are "executed".

Right now, creating these action lists looks like:

```
def build_actions():
  cmds = list()
  cmds.append(UploadSshKeys(target.get_ip(), user.get_name())
  cmds.append(RemoteAction("some command"))
...
  return cmds
```

It is nice to have those objects in the end; as they allow me to do all kind of interesting things; but on the other hand; this kind of "notation" adds a lot of "boilerplate". It would feel much nicer to have some kind of "mini-dsl"; looking like:

```
upload_keys(target.get_ip() ...
remote("some command
```

that somehow magically builds the underlying objects; puts them in a list; and provides this list in the end. A naive implementation could just provide these methods, probably looking like:

```
def upload_keys(ip, ...):
  check if there is a list, if not create one
  create the UploadSsh object
  add the object to the list
```

But seriously - doing that for many different commands sounds cumbersome and boring. I did create a similar DSL many years ago with Perl, using its "default" AUTOLOAD methods; and the easy access into the various compilation phases using BEGIN, CHECK and so on.

Long story short: I am a novice in Python; and looking for interesting (but nonetheless robust!) options to implement my "mini-dsl".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can generalize your functions like that:

```
def add_action(klass, **kwargs):
    check if there is a list, if not create one
    create the klass object with arguments **kwargs
    add the object to the list
```

then the actual methods just become:

```
def upload_keys(**kwargs):
    add_action(UploadSsh, kwargs)

def remote_action(**kwargs):
    add_action(RemoteAction, kwargs)
```

then you can call them like:

```
upload_keys(target.get_ip(), user.get_name())
remote_action("Some command")
```